# Raspberry Pi 4B giving 0.3V output when GPIO is set to True or High

Tags: gpio, pi-4, voltage

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B, 4GB version. When I try to run the following code it gives 0.3V output. I mean it works, on-0.3V, off-0V. But I need 3.3V output. I measured it with a voltmeter, as the interested device was not working getting only 0.3V from Pi.

```
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)
print ("LED on")
GPIO.output(21,True)
time.sleep(10)
print ("LED off")
GPIO.output(21,False)
```

Comment: disconnect the `interested device` and measure again

Comment: What is the interested device?

Comment: I am just using a tiny dc pump!

Comment: your trying to power ANY pump directly from the GPIO? Not going to work..   What is the current required for this pump? GPIO pins can only supply 16mA if I rememeber correctly.

Comment: You could damage your Pi by connecting a dc pump directly!

Comment: It looks like your python code is going to set the GPIO high for ten seconds then set it back off.  Set the `time.sleep` to `120` and try again. That will give you enough time to get the measurement on a multimeter. Or you're going to need to measure it with an oscilloscope. Disconnect everything from your GPIO before attempting to measure it.

Comment: Also be aware that the specific pin you were already using to power the pump might be damaged and no longer function. I would disconnect your pump, change to a different pin, and just use a meter to test/confirm the on/off gives the voltage you expect, then you could re-test the pin you were using and see if its still functional. Once you have that all sorted, I would use the GPIO pin to control a relay, which would then provide the needed power to the pump. having the physical separation between the PI and any electromagnetic motor is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in Comments (in response to your comment - which should be edited into your Question) the GPIO can only source a maximum of 16 mA and may be damaged.

You need a transistor or similar to control higher currents. There are hundreds of Answers on this site with recommended circuits (depending on the specifications of the pump).

Answer (score 0):

GPIO have extremely limited current output; when overloaded, the voltage drops to near zero. This is a clear indication that you have **"screwed up"**.

Use a *transistor* (or amplifier) to drive your `"tiny dc pump"` as shown in the schematic below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS4ESG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>